# Azure appservice how to connect to SQL Server in the VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I have api appservice in my azure and also I have VM with SQL Server installed.
Now I would like to connect to the database on the vm. I keep getting the following connection error when provide the connection string to api as :

```
Server=db-svr;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server))
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)

My VM -> Overview : There is no DNS name configured and no public ipaddress.
That is the reason I used computer name.

Also the VM->Networking has got the following inbound rule.

[image]

Can anyone help how to connect my app service to the SQL Server database available in this VM?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because they have to talk to each other over the internet, so you have to provide a proper dns name for the sql server or use a static Public IP for it.

You can, technically, use vpn in webapp, but that complicates things a bit.

Comment: Thank you. I am completely new to azure and VM things. Would you mind provide me a link or direct me to find how to give dns name for a VM. Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn

Comment: Thank you. I can see a static private ip address configured for the VM. will it be helpful? Both Public Ipaddress and DNS name is not been configured in the VM.

Comment: like i said, you need to either add public ip or use vnet integration for the webapp. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: _..have to..talk to each other over the internet.._ --  just a heads up, it's not Internet in the sense of the dark scary place, it's merely the public IP of another scale unit somewhere in the same datacenter, so the traffic never really leaves the routing domain of _that_ datacenter unless the DB VM is in a different region.

Comment: i have added a public address in the IP Configurations but not able to find a way to assign this public ipaddress to the Network Interface which is assigned to my VM.

Comment: i've linked the article (official one) which explains how to do that